# How to debug a custom OLE Automation server where SQL Server initiates?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, com, visual-studio-2015, ole

Need to know how to debug a custom C++ OLE COM object I am developing in Visual Studio Community 2015.

I am able to debug if I am using cscript to initiate.. however the issue i am trying to resolve appears only occur when called from SQL Server 2008 R2. Unfortunately there is no error thrown, it is JNI related used within the COM and the COM object simply returns without a result.

Anyone know how i can initiate this from SQL Server using Visual Studio Community 2015? Basically I want to debug the OLE COM once the SQL call is made. I tried SQLCMD but it did not allow debugging as was the case with cscript

Answer (score 0):

Two cases:
1) In-process Server (File extension is .dll): Just same as ordinary debugging, but the debug COM needs to be registered.
2) Out-of-process Server )File extension is .dll): Set the .exe program as start up program and put "/debug" parameter in the command line in "debug" setting. The process will be loaded and stop at the breakpoint. With no doubt, the exe should be registered as well.

Comment: DLL In the end I decided to add blind write to a dummy debug txt file so i can determine whats gone wrong. Based on this i now know that the issue is the JNI, which fails to start a JVM on the 2nd call (could not find the 1st instance). Still debugging.. but thats a separate issue.